# SQL Efficiencies

Tags: sql, query-performance

Say I had the following table

```
-----------------------------
-- ID     | DATE           --
-- 01     | 1577836799998  --
-- 02     | 1577836799999  --
-- 03     | 1577836800000  --
-- 04     | 1577836800001  --
-----------------------------
```

I wish to select all data IDs relative to a timestamp. Is it more efficient to convert the timestamp (1) before or (2) after the operator? How does this impact efficiency?

(1)

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATEADD(MS, DATE, '1970-01-01') > '2020-01-01'
```

(2)

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE > DATE_PART('EPOCH_MILLISECOND', TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01'))
```

Would it be the latter (2)? Because it only has to convert the comparison timestamp once without converting every single date in the table to compare?

Comment: You have tagged three different database products. Which DBMS do you really use? But in general the second one will be able to make use of an index on `date`, whereas the first one not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, my question is for general. I am learning multiple DBMS. I would think this logic would apply to many of them

Comment: "I would think this logic". Correct the login would apply, but this is not a question of the logic it is a question of how the particular DBMS implements. And every DBMS is different.  Example in (1) you use function DATEADD but that function does not exist in Posrgres.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking which of these is more efficient:

```
WHERE DATEADD(MS, DATE, '1970-01-01') > '2020-01-01'
WHERE DATE > DATE_PART('EPOCH_MILLISECOND', TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01'))
```

First, they may result in the same execution plan, so there might be no difference.

That said, the second is much, much preferable.  Why?  The data has information about columns, such as:

- Available indexes
- Available partitions
- Statistics

These can be used to choose the best query plan.  So, you have more options with the second method, because the "bare" column is better understood than the column that is the argument to a function.